# Translating expressions into English

Tags: programming-languages

I am curious as to this problem:

( | ) * a
with alphabet Σ = {, }

I am suppose to translate this function into English. What I'm not too sure on is the |, and *.

Is the answer to this: "a followed by some combination of a or b, followed by a"

Comment: This doesn't seem like it has anything to do with programming or programming languages. This looks like logic notation maybe?

Comment: `|` is alternation/"or" and asterisk is a [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star). You can hopefully take it from there.

Comment: @ggorlen can you further explain the Kleene star?